# Equation of line on the complex plane

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm currently reading a book titled **Complex Numbers and Geometry** by Liang-shin Hahn, and I'm having trouble understanding the concept of a line in the complex plane as presented in the book.

The equation of a line $l$ is presented as $z+k\bar z=2p\alpha$, where $\alpha$ is the unit vector perpendicular to $l$, $p$ is the distance from the origin to $l$ (thus p is real), and $k=\frac {\alpha}{\bar \alpha}$.  It is derived from the fact that $$\frac {z-p\alpha}{\alpha} + \frac {\bar z-p\bar \alpha}{\bar \alpha} = 0,$$ as $z-p\alpha$ is a vector on $l$ and is perpendicular to the vector $\alpha$.

(algebraic manipulation obtains the equation, firstly by isolating 2p on the right side, then multiplying everything by $\alpha$ and simplifying $k=\frac {\alpha}{\bar \alpha}$ to $k$)

The section I'm stuck on has to do with proving the Simson Theorem, and the theorem is stated as such:

Given $\triangle$ABC and a point D, let P, Q, R be the feet of the perpendiculars from the point D to the sides BC, CA, AB, respectively.  Then the points P, Q, R are collinear if and only if D is on the circumcircle of $\triangle$ABC.

The book first finds the equation of the line BC, which is given by

$$\det \left( \begin{matrix} z & \bar z & 1\cr \beta & \bar \beta &  1\cr \gamma & \bar \gamma & 1 \end{matrix}\right) $$

which in turn can be rewritten as $z+\beta\gamma\bar z=\beta+\gamma$. 
What I'm unclear about is where the determinant of the matrix is derived from, and how it relates to the original equation of the line as derived in the book.

Answer (score 0):

I totally forgot about a previous section in the book, and now I see the answer to my own question.  Three points $z_1$, $z_2$ and $z_3$are collinear if and only if $$\det \begin{pmatrix}z_1 & \bar z_1 & 1\\z_2 & \bar z_2 & 1\\z_3 & \bar z_3 & 1\end{pmatrix}=0,$$ which was proved in the book.
After expansion of the matrix in my question, it does indeed fulfill the requirements for the equation of the straight line.
A page on Wikipedia about generalised circles (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalised_circle) also offers another derivation on the equation of a straight line, as well as more information.